# android emulator sd card "your SD card is full"

Tags: android, emulation, android-sdcard

i edited an existing emulator to have an sd card of size 9mb and i added a boolean in the hardware section to support sd card. when i start the app it says "your SD card is full", what do?

Comment: make the size 100mb and test...most SD cards on phones are 4GB or larger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, try making the SD card larger - like, 100 MB - and restarting the emulator. The boolean in the hardware section, IIRC, triggers the preferred location for the application's APK - internal memory or SD card. An APK of 9MB is not that uncommon.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your SD card **size** has been declared **too small**. Consider the practicability of a user having a 9MB SD card when the whole world is talking in GBs.

Edit the emulator and increase the size, atleast to a hundred as depending upon your application, you might be needing a lot of space.

However, see this post regarding a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7038) on SD card size.